# I see a flood of requests from Revista22

Tags: security, debian

In many of the sites I am running I see in Google Analytics thousands of visits referred from a site called revista22.ro, which I don't know and which mentions nothing about any of my sites.

Also, I have many records in my server's access.log like below:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:06 +0100] "GET /?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 17504 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:08 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 663 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/40.0.2214.111 Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:11 +0100] "GET /?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 17449 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:13 +0100] "GET /?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 17505 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/40.0.2214.111 Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:14 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 663 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:16 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 663 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/4.2.2.38484 Mobile/12B410 Safari/9537.53"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:16 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 663 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:16 +0100] "GET /?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 17507 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:16 +0100] "GET /?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 17505 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:18 +0100] "GET /?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 17507 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 8_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) GSA/4.2.2.38484 Mobile/12B410 Safari/9537.53"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:22 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 663 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:23 +0100] "GET /?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 17508 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:31 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 663 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:33 +0100] "GET /?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 17508 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:43 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 605 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:43 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 605 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:44 +0100] "GET /?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 17447 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:44 +0100] "GET /?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 17448 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2015:18:28:48 +0100] "GET /?lang=en HTTP/1.1" 200 17449 "http://www.revista22.ro/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0"
```

Its very strange to me that the host mentioned is the localhost...

Anyone else experience such an issue with revista22.ro?
Do you see some kind of danger based on the data in access.log?

Comment: Looks like referrer spam to me.

Comment: Are the entries in the access.log normal then?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the access log you have posted, they are not doing anything abnormal. No weird queries or questionable POST requests.

If the volume of requests from this host is very high, you should consider firewalling or rate limiting them.

You can try to rate limit them with the following iptables rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 37.156.33.207 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 37.156.33.207 -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 60 --hitcount 4 -j DROP
```

Comment: Could you please explain to me why I see 127.0.0.1 as the host of the requests? Also, actually the iptables solution didn't work. Probably because the request do not originate from the IP of the site revista22.ro. I have tried various .htaccess solutions to stop referer spam, but my access.log is still flooded by their requests.

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy to serve the website?

Comment: Νο. Only these rivets requests are having 127.0.0.1 as hosts